# approximation algorithm for optimization version of partitioning?

Tags: algorithm, approximation

in optimization version of partitioning problem we want to partition set `X` to disjoint subset `A` and `B` such that `max(sum(A),sum(B))` be minimal.A approximation algorithm has been suggested in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Approximation_algorithm_approaches), but I can't understand why this approximation is 4/3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OPT >= sum(all)/2
```

consider that the greedy algorithm give you some answer like S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>2</sub> where:

> max(sum(S<sub>1</sub>), sum(S<sub>2</sub>)) > 4/3 OPT

(without losing generality assume sum(S<sub>1</sub>) > sum(S<sub>2</sub>)) so we have :

> sum(S<sub>1</sub>) > 4/3 OPT >= 2 sum(all)/3

so :

> sum(S<sub>1</sub>) > 4/3 OPT >= 2 sum(all)/3 so **sum(S<sub>1</sub>) > 2 sum(all)/3**

so :

> sum(S<sub>1</sub>) > 2 sum(S<sub>2</sub>)

So in one of the steps of algorithm when sum(S<sub>1</sub>) was smaller than sum(S<sub>2</sub>) you must add an element like `A` to S<sub>1</sub> and after that you didnt add any element to S<sub>1</sub>

So `A` must be bigger than final state of sum(S<sub>2</sub>) (because  A +  sum(S<sub>1</sub>) > 2 sum(S<sub>2</sub>))

so `A` is bigger than current state sum(S<sub>1</sub>) (because current state of sum(S<sub>1</sub>) < current state of sum(S<sub>2</sub>) < final state of sum(S<sub>1</sub>) < A )

And your list is sorted in descending order, so `A` must be the first element in the sorted list(biggest element). so your s<sub>1</sub> must just contain `A` and you have.

also you know that the sum(OPT) >= A because either it contains A or the other part contains A but sum(OPT) is bigger that sum of other parts element so

```
sum(OPT) > A
```

but you have :

> A = sum(S<sub>1</sub>) > 4/3 sum(OPT) > sum(OPT) > A

and it is a contradiction :)

Comment: thanks for your answer...I think at the end we as I understand the OPT is A so we have A=sum(S_1) > 4/3OPT = 4/3A because in the optimal solution A must be in one partition and all other elements at the other partition.Again thanks to your answer @Ali

Comment: at the end opt is something bigger than A and also something smaller than A and it is a contradiction ;) your welcome :)

Comment: why it is bigger than A ? I think sum(OPT) > A must be sum(OPT) = A  and in this case the contradiction also remain.

Comment: no my bad it is not bigger, it is equal or bigger than A, I mean : sum(OPT) >= A